# I'm stuck configuring Gruntfile.js to transpile multiple JS files into one

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-babel

I've replaced uglify with babel (and concat), so I'm concat'ing multiple ES6 files into one distribution JS file.  I'd LIKE to concat into the dist folder, and have babel transpile and overwrite the file but doing that, babel is unable to use the dist FOLDER, warning:
    Couldn't find preset “env” relative to directory

What am I doing wrong?

my Gruntfile.js:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      concat: {
        options: {
          /*sourceMap: true,
          sourceMapStyle: "link"*/
        },
        dist: {
          src: [
            "js/file1.js",
            "js/file2.js",
            "js/file3.js",
            "js/file4.js",
            "js/file5.js"
          ],
          dest: "js/script.concat.js"
        }
      },
      babel: {
        options: {
          presets: ["env"],
          /*sourceMap: true,*/
          minified: true
        },
        dist: {
          files: [{"../dist/js/script.min.js" : "js/script.concat.js"}]
        }
      },
      watch: {
        js: {
            files: ["js/file1.js", "js/file2.js", "js/file3.js", "js/file4.js", "js/file5.js"],
          tasks: ["concat:dist", "babel:dist"]
        }
      }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-babel');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat:dist', 'babel:dist']);
};
```

Comment: Try targeting the preset like this: instead of `["env"]` use `["@babel/preset-env"]`

Comment: Well it will depend on how you installed the presets. SOrry i didnt clarify that.

Comment: Sorry, why would it depend on how the presets are installed? Surely that is always just a module?

Comment: It depends on how you installed it. Using yarn or npm. Thats the difference. One will need the `@babel` namespace. The other the full package name `babel-preset-env`. Also you could try the resolver to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: Just to clarify: I installed "babel-preset-env" because the newer "preset-env" is still in a beta state.
The preset target "env" works for file targets in the source folder. It's just when I try to use a file that has been created in the distribution folder that it fails.

Comment: When Babel tries to use a source file that is in the distribution folder, rather than in the source folder, it gives the error “Couldn't find preset “env” relative to directory” and fails to create a .js file.

Comment: Babel's [lookup behavior](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc/#lookup-behavior) is that it _" looks for a .babelrc in the current directory of the file being transpiled. If one does not exist, it will travel up the directory tree..."_. Because your `../dist` folder is located outside the root of your project directory (i.e. it's up one level) Babel _will not_ find it. You need to relocate your `dist` folder to the root of your project folder (i.e. at the same level as `src`). Saving a `.babelrc` up one level in `../dist/` or `../dist/js` also does not work. The path to `dist` must be `./dist`.